# Repository Pattern in Layered Architecture

Tags: c#, asp.net, repository-pattern, webforms

I've gone through quite a few articles on the repository pattern and had some questions.
I'm trying to implement this in a ASP.NET 4.0 application.
The architecture is a layered architecture with a Presentation Layer, Business Layer and Data Layer.
From this article, http://www.primaryobjects.com/CMS/Article108.aspx

I have created the `MYSQLRepository` (DataLayer)

```
public class MySQLRepository:IOrderRepository
{
    public List<Order> GetOrders()
    {

        List<Order> orders = new List<Order>();
        orders.Add(new Order(1,"A"));
        orders.Add(new Order(2,"B"));

        return orders;
    }
}
```

My Business Layer looks like this

```
public class OrderBL
{
    IOrderRepository orderrep;
    public OrderBL(IOrderRepository repository)
    {
       orderrep = repository;

    }

    public List<Order> GetOrders()
    {
        return orderrep.GetOrders();

    }
}
```

Now my question is that in the presentation layer, I'm expected to do this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OrderBL orderBL = new OrderBL(new MySQLRepository());
    List<Order> orders = orderBL.GetOrders();

    foreach (Order order in orders)
    {
        Response.Write(order.OrderId.ToString() + ". " + order.OrderNo + "<br>");
    }

}
```

In order to do this, I have to reference my DataLayer in the presentation layer. Isn't that wrong? Ideally I would only want to reference my Business Layer. 
IS something wrong in my implementation or is it not the right place to implement the pattern. I have seen many examples using ASP.NET MVC and it seems to work well there.

Also, Do i really need dependency injection here?

Thanks for the help
Soni

Comment: @Eranga, thanks for the edit. was wondering how to do that

Comment: select the code block and click `{}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it's better to unilize IoC to get constructor injection, this will remove unnecessary layers' references.

Comment: Thanks. My only issue is that its a very straightforward application. Not sure if I want to use a sword when a needle would do!

Comment: I think, if you don't find repository overkill then ioc would not be as well. Try Catle Windsor, Unity or StructureMap it's quite easy to setup them.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing the point and the reason why the repository pattern is so powerful. It may seem strange to call it in your presentation layer, but imagine that page needed to use a different datasource. You can just as easily swap it out with a call like:
              `orderBL orderBL = new OrderBL(new OracleRepository());`

Comment: Yes I am a little confused on the usage of the pattern. But my point is that I dont want the UI to call my data layer. I'd like to go through my business layer.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative here is you don't pass repository references around.

Your BL can instantiate the DL when it needs to. If you have cross method calls where several operations need to happen in data then use a facade layer to sit on top of your business objects. Either way then you don't need a direct reference to a data layer repository from your presentation layer. If it makes you feel even better, pull any of your Model classes (for example Order) out into a separate "Models" project.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid calling the data layer directly, you could call a function in your business layer to instatiate your repository. Your business layer could take care of the rest.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure if the pattern is just too hyped. I'm sure there must be an easier way to abstract my application from the underlying data source.